# libnuma - data types problems

Tags: c, types, numa

I'm using libnuma for an enhanced NUMA-aware allocator. There are some functions which do not work as explained in the 'numa man-page' or libnuma APIs. Precisely, I'm having problems with these functions: `numa_get_run_node_mask()` and `numa_node_to_cpus()`.
Concerning the former, reading the API and the manual it says it returns a `struct bitmask *`, while the compiler asks for a `nodemask_t`.
The latter is supposed to require two parameters, as from API definition, but the compiler asks for three. If I pass three arguments -- following this declaration I've found in the source code definition: `numa_node_to_cpus_v1(int node, unsigned long *buffer, int bufferlen)` -- I get a *segfault* every time, no matter the *bufferlen* I use.

Just to mention, the latter function `numa_node_to_cpus()` is the same `numactl` uses when you type the command `numactl --hardware`: it is used to retrieve all the cpus in a node. I read through the source code and it properly works with two arguments `int node, struct bitmask *mask`.

Maybe there are bugs that need to be fixed, or some discrepancies between APIs and source that has changed through libnuma versions. (btw, how do I check which libnuma/numactl is running on the machine? I working remotely on a server and `numactl` doesn't seem to have a `--version` option!)

Comment: Looks like you have a version problem indeed - could be that the headers you're compiling with don't match the libraries you have installed (or you're not picking up the right ones if you have multiple installed). Try and find the versions with your OS's package manager.

Comment: I checked the `numa.h` file located at `/usr/include/numa.h` and it contains the very same definitions presented in the APIs. I'll try to re-install the package's latest version and see if there are any differences.